# How to explode using integer value as delimiter

Tags: php, substring, explode, delimiter

I am getting a string value in php like this -

```
How are you|1 I am fine|2 That is fine|3
```

I want to explode this string taking delimiter to this integer value. Basically i need these 3 values from this.

```
How are you|1 
I am fine|2 
That is fine|3
```

Can anybody suggest what can i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exploding with chr(13) as delimiter.

Try this loop.

```
$extras = $db->loadRowList();

            $num=sizeof($extras);
            for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
            {               
                echo "<br>".$extras[$i][0]."<br>";    
                $arr=explode(chr(13),  $extras[$i][0]);

                $num1=sizeof($arr);
                for($j=0;$j<$num1;$j++)
                {
                    $tmp = explode('|', $arr[$j]);

                    $num2=sizeof($tmp);
                    for($k=0;$k<$num2;$k++)
                    {
                        echo $tmp[$k]."<br>";
                    }                       
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. It's chr(13), which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `preg_split()` with some regex instead of `explode()`:

```
$arr = preg_split('#(?<=\|\d )(?=[a-z])#i', "How are you|1 I am fine|2 That is fine|3");
```

Which will split the string where there is a pipe character <kbd>|</kbd> followed by a number, followed by a space.

**EDIT**

If the spaces could be new lines or carriage returns, add an or condition in there:

```
$arr = preg_split('#(?<=\|\d( |\n|\r))(?=[a-z])#i', "How are you|1 I am fine|2 That is fine|3");
```

Comment: Your code is working fine, but i got a new problem here. Please check my answer.

Comment: @gsm11001 You could simply replace all of the line breaks `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "", $str)` before-hand. Or change your regex a little: `#(?<=\|\d\n)(?=[a-z])#i`

Comment: I can not replace the line breaks as it will modify the plugin too. However in value which i am getting from database i am unable to see any line break code. Also changing the regex is not doing the trick.

Comment: Just add the line breaks back on after you have split the string? `$arr = array_map(function($v){ return $v."\n"; }, $arr)`

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but ironically it's not working fine. I don't know how but that line break issue does not seem to be resolved yet. I am posting the output, what i am getting. Please help me one more time.

Answer (score 2):

Try with [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
$str     = 'How are you|1 I am fine|2 That is fine|3';
$pattern = '/(\D+)(\d+)/';
$res     = preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trick from [65Fbef05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860238/exploding-by-array-of-delimiters)

In your case will be

```
$str = 'How are you|1 I am fine|2 That is fine|3';
$del = array(1, 2, 3);

// In one fell swoop...
$arr = explode( $del[0], str_replace($del, $del[0], $str) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bruzetti. However i can't use your code bcz in my database those integers are not always in increasing order. But i am giving you a +1, as this code is quite correct.