# PHP: explode with array delimiter

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have the string `$content` with an big and aleatory text. I want to explode `$content` and the delimiter was the first occourcence of any value in the array `$array_explode`. Could anyone help me?

Something like that:

```
$content="...";
$array_explode = array("<br>", "<p>", "<h2>", "<h1>", "<h3>");
$content_explode = explode($array_explode, $content);
```

Comment: It is `preg_split`

Comment: I think you'd be better off using the DOM functions for this.  They are specifically designed for XML / HTML markup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860238/exploding-by-array-of-delimiters

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$content = "...";
$content = str_replace(array("<br>", "<p>", "<h2>", "<h1>", "<h3>"), array("<br>".chr(30), "<p>".chr(30), "<h2>".chr(30), "<h1>".chr(30), "<h3>".chr(30)), $content);
$content_explode = explode(chr(30), $content);

?>
```