# Explode or str_split by values

Tags: php, explode

I have multiple inputs of ingredients set out like so.

3x carrots
1/2 cups milk (or could be 1/2 cups of milk)
1 tsp of olive oil

and I also have a list of ingredients and units of measurement so I can check if they are in the string.

Now I have no idea how to split the string based on values from my ingredient or units list

All I can think of is starting by checking if the word of is in the array like so

```
$listIngredients = // a massive list pulled from the database like below 
$units           = ['x', 'cup', 'tsp'];
$results         = [];
foreach($result->recipe_ingredients as $ingredient)
{
  $results = strtr($ingredient, 'of ', '');
  $results = explode($ingredient); 
  // using str_plural() I want to check if ingredient or units of measurement exist. then
  // split them if they do so I have an array having the number, then unit, then ingredient
  // then I will save each in the database under different columns. 
}
```

or would there be a better way of doing this? maybe checking for when there is a space or int stops eg. 3x carrots or 1/2 cups. im so confused >_<

EDIT: I thought id throw this out there, I know explode requires 2 parameters. my question is more in regards to what parameters, if I need more than 2, e.g. I want to check the string for a int, unit and also a ingredient.

Comment: can you provide a simple list of input and output you expect? your question is also so confusing >_<

Comment: `$results = explode($ingredient); ` - needs 2 parameter. you are passing only one.

Comment: `strtr` always returns string after transformation .... and you are applying foreach over result of `strtr`

Comment: explode function in PHP requires 2 parameters: explode(delimeter, string)

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes yeah updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure how you mean

> I thought id throw this out there, I know explode requires 2
>   parameters. my question is more in regards to what parameters, if I
>   need more than 2, e.g. I want to check the string for a int, unit and
>   also a ingredient.

But my guess is, that you should check:
[Exploding by Array of Delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860238/exploding-by-array-of-delimiters)

Also you could use this to check if string contains part of string with this simple old solution (case insensitive with strtolower())

```
if (strpos(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle)) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

I'd try to explode the strings with your list of keyphrases and then explode array elements again untill there are no usable keyphrases left. Also you should append the delimeter that had been used to the element on the left, so you don't loose your ingredient (with some kind of blank character so it'd prevent reapeated splitting).

Comment: Cheers for that. Helped a lot as i had no idea where to start or if its even a backend solution. I might even use js on the frontend checking for a space then autocomplete the unit then ingredient. This way i know the values.