# PHP separate string by specific array of words

Tags: php

I've array in php with following values

```
Array
(
    [0] => Clarithromycin 250mg/5ml oral susptake TWO 5ml spoonsful TWICE each day DISCARD REMAINING AFTER TEN DAYSSHAKE THE BOTTLE WELL BEFORE USING.SPACE THE DOSES EVENLY. KEEP TAKING UNTIL THE COURSE IS FINISHED, UNLESS YOU ARE TOLD TO STOP.
    [1] => Lactulose 3.1-3.7g/5ml oral solntake ONE to FOUR 5ml spoonsful TWICE each day when required (PRN : to be taken when necessary)
    [2] => Mirtazapine orodisp 30mg tabsOne To Be Taken At NightALLOW THE TABLETS TO DISSOLVE ON YOUR TONGUE, THEN SWALLOW WITH THE SALIVA. TAKE AFTER FOOD.WARNING: THIS MEDICINE MAY MAKE YOU FEEL SLEEPY. IF THIS HAPPENS, DO NOT DRIVE OR USE TOOLS OR MACHINES. DO NOT DRINK ALCOHOL.
    [3] => Senna 7.5mg/5ml oral soln SFTwo 5ml Spoonfuls To Be Taken At NightSHAKE THE BOTTLE WELL BEFORE USING.THIS MEDICINE MAY COLOUR YOUR URINE. THIS IS HARMLESS.
    [4] => SUDOCREM ANTISEPTIC HEALING CREAMas directedFOR EXTERNAL USE ONLY. (MD mean As directed)
    [5] => CIRCADIN MR 2MG TABSOne To Be Taken At NightSWALLOW WHOLE. DO NOT CHEW OR CRUSH.TAKE WITH OR JUST AFTER FOOD, OR A MEAL.WARNING: THIS MEDICINE MAY MAKE YOU FEEL SLEEPY. IF THIS HAPPENS, DO NOT DRIVE OR USE TOOLS OR MACHINES. DO NOT DRINK ALCOHOL.
    [6] => Memantine 10mg tabsOne To Be Taken Each Day
    [7] => Omeprazole gr 10mg capsOne To Be Taken Each DaySWALLOW WHOLE.DO NOT CHEW OR CRUSH.
    [8] => Senna 7.5mg tabsTwo To Be Taken At NightTHIS MEDICINE MAY COLOUR YOUR URINE. THIS IS HARMLESS.
)
```

I wanna separate medicine and description by specific words. e.g (take two,one to be taken,one to,to be taken etc.....)

```
array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [medicine] => Clarithromycin 250mg/5ml oral susp
            [description] => take TWO 5ml spoonsful TWICE each day DISCARD REMAINING AFTER TEN DAYSSHAKE THE BOTTLE WELL BEFORE USING.SPACE THE DOSES EVENLY. KEEP TAKING UNTIL THE COURSE IS FINISHED, UNLESS YOU ARE TOLD TO STOP.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [medicine] => Lactulose 3.1-3.7g/5ml oral soln
            [description] =>take ONE to FOUR 5ml spoonsful TWICE each day when required (PRN : to be taken when necessary)
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [medicine] => Mirtazapine orodisp 30mg tabs
            [description] => One To Be Taken At NightALLOW THE TABLETS TO DISSOLVE ON YOUR TONGUE, THEN SWALLOW WITH THE SALIVA. TAKE AFTER FOOD.WARNING: THIS MEDICINE MAY MAKE YOU FEEL SLEEPY. IF THIS HAPPENS, DO NOT DRIVE OR USE TOOLS OR MACHINES. DO NOT DRINK ALCOHOL.
        )
.
.
.
.
)
```

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: From where are you scraping the data?, maybe you can add more checks on the source.

Comment: We've list of keywords mention in question e.g (take two,one to be taken,one to,to be taken etc.....) if any of word found in string split it.

Comment: What would sentence "take one. more words. one to be taken with food" split to?

Comment: Also [here's a sandbox boilerplate](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/62741d55e6cab45da479fa1344f05670007efc4c) if anyone needs it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exploding by Array of Delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860238/exploding-by-array-of-delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $explode = explode('separate', $value);
    $array[$key] = array(
        'medicine' => $explode[0],
        'description' => $explode[1]
    );
}
```

just edit 'separate' by the word you want to seperate your text with

Answer (score 0):

```
//Main array
//Create array of words that you have to separate from
$arrOfsplittedData = [];
$intCount = 0;
foreach($arrOfMedicineAndDesc as $medicineAndDesc){
    $lowerCaseMedicineAndDesc = strtolower($medicineAndDesc);
    $splitMedicineAndDesc = multiexplode(array("oral", "tabsone", "cream", "capsone", "tabstwo"), $lowerCaseMedicineAndDesc);
    if($splitMedicineAndDesc){
        $arrOfsplittedData[$intCount]["medicine"] =          $splitMedicineAndDesc[0];
        $arrOfsplittedData[$intCount]["description"] = $splitMedicineAndDesc[1];
    }
    $intCount++;
}

function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {    
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrOfsplittedData);die;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be crafty with regex to do this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "Clarithromycin 250mg/5ml oral susptake TWO 5ml spoonsful TWICE each day DISCARD REMAINING AFTER TEN DAYSSHAKE THE BOTTLE WELL BEFORE USING.SPACE THE DOSES EVENLY. KEEP TAKING UNTIL THE COURSE IS FINISHED, UNLESS YOU ARE TOLD TO STOP.",
    "Lactulose 3.1-3.7g/5ml oral solntake ONE to FOUR 5ml spoonsful TWICE each day when required (PRN : to be taken when necessary)",
    "Mirtazapine orodisp 30mg tabsOne To Be Taken At NightALLOW THE TABLETS TO DISSOLVE ON YOUR TONGUE, THEN SWALLOW WITH THE SALIVA. TAKE AFTER FOOD.WARNING: THIS MEDICINE MAY MAKE YOU FEEL SLEEPY. IF THIS HAPPENS, DO NOT DRIVE OR USE TOOLS OR MACHINES. DO NOT DRINK ALCOHOL.",
    "Senna 7.5mg/5ml oral soln SFTwo 5ml Spoonfuls To Be Taken At NightSHAKE THE BOTTLE WELL BEFORE USING.THIS MEDICINE MAY COLOUR YOUR URINE. THIS IS HARMLESS.",
    "SUDOCREM ANTISEPTIC HEALING CREAMas directedFOR EXTERNAL USE ONLY. (MD mean As directed)",
    "CIRCADIN MR 2MG TABSOne To Be Taken At NightSWALLOW WHOLE. DO NOT CHEW OR CRUSH.TAKE WITH OR JUST AFTER FOOD, OR A MEAL.WARNING: THIS MEDICINE MAY MAKE YOU FEEL SLEEPY. IF THIS HAPPENS, DO NOT DRIVE OR USE TOOLS OR MACHINES. DO NOT DRINK ALCOHOL.",
    "Memantine 10mg tabsOne To Be Taken Each Day",
    "Omeprazole gr 10mg capsOne To Be Taken Each DaySWALLOW WHOLE.DO NOT CHEW OR CRUSH.",
    "Senna 7.5mg tabsTwo To Be Taken At NightTHIS MEDICINE MAY COLOUR YOUR URINE. THIS IS HARMLESS."
);

$splitWords = [
    "take \w+?\b",
    "to be taken"
]; //Regex of what you want to split on

$regex = "/(".implode("|",$splitWords).")/";



$replaced = preg_replace($regex, "\n$1", $array); //Replace what you found with a newline + what you found

print_r(array_map(function ($v) { 
    $array = explode("\n",$v); 
    return [ 
        "medicine" => $array[0], 
        "description" => isset($array[1])?$array[1]:null
    ]; //If you're array is bigger than 2 elements you may need to loop here.
},$replaced)); //Split sentences on the newlines.
```

Here's an example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2e2ceef17152e9a888a7b68fab3acb2e9f10fe3